# How to handle localStorage .setItem and .removeItem with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a chrome extension which should listen to `localStorage` changes in a content script on a given website.

Website sets local storage with `window.localStorage.setItem('test', 'test');`

I want to bind a listener to storage changes as

```
$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
   alert('storage changed');
});
```

But, given code only works when I go to Chrome `Inspect > Application > Local Storage` and remove something or add.

I also tried to run a

```
var test = window.localStorage.setItem('test','test');
```

just below my `binding` still doesn't work.

How can I listen to localStorage changes in this case?

Comment: `storage` event is not fired in the same document so it won't help you. You can try spoofing `localStorage` using DOM `Proxy` API inside a [script element (to make it run in page context)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879). In addition to `setItem` you'll need to spoof `set` too. It's highly likely you can find an existing example, so do some googling.

Comment: Create a function that generates a hash of localStorage contents and compares that with an earlier hash. Set timeout for a function to run every x ms.. this way you can see if storage has changed across sessions/tabs/windows

Comment: @wOxxOm I mentioned that I tried to run it at same document, too. Why it doesn't work in that case?

Comment: Because that's how this event works as per the specification.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
`$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
   alert('storage changed');
});
var test = window.localStorage.setItem('test','test');
` 
this code doesn't work, even at the same window, why it should work this way? if I am binding my storage to listen to events

Comment: Like I said, `storage` event won't help here.